# What is the substitute idiom for sapply in data.table?

Tags: r, data.table

I just want to calculate the maximum values for each column separately. Using simple `sapply` went into a memory overflow:

```
 # dt is my data.table object
 res <- sapply(dt, max, na.rm=T) # fails due to memory problems
```

It is a sparse table of 1 million rows and 1000 columns, with an overall size of 11 GB.

I am working on the file [*train_date.csv*](https://www.kaggle.com/c/bosch-production-line-performance/data) and use the following lines of code:

```
require(data.table)
dtDate <- fread(paste0(filePath, "train_date.csv"))
dim(dtDate)
require(pryr)
object_size(dtDate)
```

Comment: What is exactly the code you've used? What is the data size? What are your specs? Did you read [this](https://rawgit.com/wiki/Rdatatable/data.table/vignettes/datatable-intro.html) ? There are examples of *idiom* for `lapply` usage and much more.

Comment: Maybe, it will be better to use `apply(df, 2, max)`.

Comment: It is a sparse table of 1 mio rows and 1000 columns, with an overall size of 11 GB @DavidArenburg.

Comment: This is not how you run `data.table` code. You should read the intro I've linked above

Comment: The answer of mpjdem follows this recommendation from the data.table FAQ page: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/data.table/vignettes/datatable-faq.html#how-can-i-avoid-writing-a-really-long-j-expression-youve-said-that-i-should-use-the-column-names-but-ive-got-a-lot-of-columns.

Comment: What I really don't like about packages like sparklyr, data.table, and so on is that they assume analysis scenarios where you can refer to each of your columns by names. This is seldomly the case for high-dimensional data. I really wonder what data analysis scenarios the developers had in mind. Most of the packages fail on simple things like doing a function call to each column, if you have 1000 columns. This is the same problem as with sparklyr.

Comment: Re your comment, I hear that finance and genetics have large data sets where ordering and groups (which is what many data.table features are built around) matter. And I use it with smallish data sets for the nice syntax. If you are using a sparse matrix, you should google a package designed for such a thing rather than shoehorning it into spark or data.table, I guess. Also, you could google column maxes in R to find `colMaxs`.

Comment: @Felix: thanks! Your assumption is right. I am originally a Bioinformatician, but this file includes sensor data in the industry 4.0 field. Thanks for the tipps!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Warning, a very large table will be created!

```
dt <- as.data.table(matrix(runif(1000*1000000),ncol=1000))
dt[,lapply(.SD,max)]
```

Comment: Thanks, but this doesn't work. It resulted in a data.table with data.frames included.

Comment: Then something is wrong with your setup or your data. It should work. I included an example data.table above that works perfectly for me.

Comment: Thank you very much. I will go and check my code to see what is messing it up.

Comment: How does this answer the memory overflow question?

Comment: For some strange reason, the resulting data.table res in 'res <- dt[, {lapply(.SD,max, na.rm=T)}]' includes all column names instead of the maximum values.

Comment: @DavidArenburg It answered the question in the title. If a memory problem still exists afterwards, we'll see about it then (should be easy to circumvent in case of max...)

CodingButStillAlive: Did you parse the header line of csv files as a row, or something like that? Are your columns numeric?

Comment: @mpjdem: I used the function fread with no further parameters.

Comment: I added a link to the concrete csv file in my question, in case someone wants to check it. However, there is something strange anyways, as the 2.9 GB file leaves a memory footprint of 11GB inside R. See my related question: https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/1959

Comment: @CodingButStillAlive Please just run `is.numeric` on one of the columns and if it is `FALSE`, check whether `colname %in% col` is `TRUE`, substituting colname for your column name and col for the actual column. I'm asking because if your columns are numbers converted to characters and the column name is also somewhere among its values, then it would indeed show up as the maximum value of that column.

Comment: I did: `> is.numeric(dtDate[,3])
[1] FALSE
> colnames(dtDate)[3] %in% dtDate[,3]
[1] FALSE`

Comment: I tried using the actual file. My code does work; however the console output will list the column names first and since there are so many, you won't see the maximal values anymore. But they are there, if you extract one column at a time

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/130130/discussion-between-codingbutstillalive-and-mpjdem).

Comment: Thanks, you are right. I dunno why I had not seen this. I am very sorry for the efforts.

Comment: I had just checked with `res[1]` instead of `res[,1]` cause I was expecting a vector or list as the result. Stupid mistake :(